# Consulta SQL en SQL SERVER 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen dia a todos

Requiero realizar la siguiente consulta: [image: Resultado de la consulta]

Tengo el siguiente modelo relacional: [image: Modelo relacional]

Hasta el momento solo he consultado la cantidad de barrios por localidad pero no he logrado contar la cantidad de habitantes supongo que en este caso seria por localidad.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.localidades.nombre_localidad AS Localidades, 
    COUNT(dbo.barrios.localidad) AS Numero_de_barrios
    FROM localidades 
        JOIN barrios ON localidades.id_localidad = barrios.localidad
    GROUP BY nombre_localidad;
```

Alguien me podria colaborar o darme una idea.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si, ordena lo que queres.. saca de a uno cada valor... imposible saber con solo ver tu modelo donde estan los datos que necesitas... si ese query funciona, que dificultad tuviste agregando el que cuenta poblacion?

Comment: Tu modelo de datos no muestra que puedas hacer una consulta histórica correcta, ya que no hay fechas de inicio y final para la vivienda, o fechas del censo. No sabes si alguien se mudó al barrio y cuando. En todo caso, solo podrías obtener a los habitantes registrados que nacieron antes de la fecha establecida.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
dbo.localidades.nombre_localidad AS Localidades, 
COUNT(dbo.barrios.localidad) AS Numero_de_barrios,
COUNT(miembros.id_miembro) AS Numero_de_miembros
FROM localidades 
    JOIN barrios ON localidades.id_localidad = barrios.localidad
    JOIN familias ON barrios.id_barrio= familia.barrio
    JOIN miembros ON familia.id_familia = miembros.familia
GROUP BY nombre_localidad;
```

Comment: Aunque las consultas sql se explican a ellas mismas, añadir una explicación a la respuesta, y cómo resuelve el problema de OP, puede enriquecerla.